# Is there any way to create a folder with the same name as a variable and then put a JSON file on it in python?

Tags: python, json, directory

Hi i am trying to create a folder that jas the same name of a variable and then write a JSON file inside that folder. Currently mi code looks something like this:

```
a = "name"
filename = "Configs/" + a + "/" + a
with open (filename, 'w') as f_obj:
json.dump(data, f_obj)
```

After that I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError : [Errno 2] no such file or directory : 'Configs/name/name'
```

When I try:

```
 filename = "Configs/" + a
```

It works perfectly, I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the directory `Configs/name` exist? You probably need to create that first (e.g. `pathlib.Path("Configs/" + a).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)`

Comment: That actually works! Thank you very much kind stranger, is there any way to mark this as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open` can create new files to be written to, but it won't create new directories to put them in. The error you're getting is because the directory `Configs/name` doesn't exist - you need to create this first, then create the file inside of it. Here's one way to do this:

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path

data = {} # whatever your data is
a = "name"
file_path = Path("Configs") / a / a
file_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) # if these flags are right for you
file_path.write_text(json.dumps(data))
```